# Online account can't be added

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, netplan

I wanted to add my work calendar to my home system running Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome and I get a message indicating there is "no internet connection - connect to set up new online accounts". I'm assuming it is because I setup my internet using netplan so gnome settings (network manager?) doesn't manage the link. Is there any work around for getting this service up and running?

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same problem, funny how it is isn't answered yet!

Comment: I recently noticed that I am unable to install or update through the software center. Do you have the same problem as well? Obviously, I don't use it as a rule, but it is curious. I may file a bug report as this is a pretty big problem albeit for a small subset of users.

Comment: Hey I found a solution and this worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155478/ubuntu-desktop-gnome-no-internet-connection-on-19-04

Comment: That is certainly a solution for most but I have more of an edge case. I am using a bonded (lacp) connection and my research hasn't shown me how to do that with network manager and networkd.