# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server gnome-software not working Pi4-8G

Tags: networking, server, wireless, 22.04, gnome-software

i am having issues getting gnome-software to work, as you can see in the images below, it thinks i have no network. i clearly do as i am connected through the network via Realvnc.
i have tried

```
sudo apt remove gnome-software
sudo apt install gnome-software
sudo apt reinstall gnome-software
```

i also tried a reset

dconf reset -f /org/gnome/  #from a terminal on desktop

[Gnome desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx9a4.png)

[gnome-software update tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecMaD.png)

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar issue on an older version , but the steps below fixed my issue. the gnome environment the now 100%.

I hope this helps someone else as well.

If you wish for Network Manager to control networking, rather than netplan, remove the existing netplan file:

```
sudo rm /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

Create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc. Please proofread carefully twice. Save and exit nano.

After making these changes, do:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Then reboot

```
sudo reboot now
```

[Gnome WiFi working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISvCK.png)

Thanx to the original post
[Ubuntu desktop GNOME "no Internet connection" on 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155478/ubuntu-desktop-gnome-no-internet-connection-on-19-04)

Comment: i did this but without success.   (only difference was that i just created the new file without deleting the old file as i am told that the `01` preceeds the `50` anyway).

Comment: Excellent this solve my problem.